# how can I connect midnight commander with vimdiff?

Tags: vimdiff

I've mananged to connect mc(midnight commanger) with vim.
But unfortunatley I couldn't find a way to connect it with vimdiff.
Is there a way to replace mcdiff with vimdiff??